# Upload file from desktop to Java applet application

Tags: java, applet, signed-applet

How I can upload a file from desktop to Java applet application?

1. Create upload button.
2. Browse thought the desktop and choose the file.
3. Then create a link that enables the user to click on and open the chosen file.

Answer (score 0):

1. use swing for example, just a button
2. use JFileChooser
3. It is not clear: do you want a link where ? (if it is on the web, you have to transmit it, or it can be on the applet: why not a button ?), and does it be called another time ?

General question: what is the purpose of this file ?

Comment: I want to be able to open the file from the application. I intend to later embed the application in web.

Comment: @R.Y.H, it should be more clear, if the client side leaves alone, or if there is some process with a server. You'll have to solve securities problem to (autorization for applet). My advice: dont use an applet. With HTML5 / javascript, you can do a lot of things, event on the user PC.